# Create chart using css, css-doodle, or bootstrap

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, two.js, css-doodle

I am looking to generate a rectangle shape of 12 houses chart using CSS. The best I could use is CSS-doodle code below; even that it is nowhere perfect. 
How can the example images below can be accomplished? The structure has to be a single structure, and I want to add text to all houses.

```
<css-doodle >
 :doodle {

  overflow: hidden;
  height:14em; width:16em;
  @grid: 4;
}
:container {
  grid-gap: 1px;
  transform: rotate(45deg) scale(1.5);
}
  background: #d0262e;
</css-doodle>
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an idea with one element and some background tricks. It's also responsive, you can resize the element and the structure will be kept the same. I also considered `order` to correctly place the elements

```css
.box {
  width:280px;
  height:180px;
  border:3px solid;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  background:
    linear-gradient(to top right,transparent calc(50% - 2px), #000 calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px),transparent calc(50% + 2px)),
    linear-gradient(to top left ,transparent calc(50% - 2px), #000 calc(50% - 1px) calc(50% + 1px),transparent calc(50% + 2px));
  background-size:50% 50%;
   
  counter-reset:num;
  overflow:hidden;
  resize:both;
}
.box span {
  flex-grow:1;
  flex-basis:50%;
  height:25%;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
.box span:nth-child(3),
.box span:nth-child(5),
.box span:nth-child(9),
.box span:nth-child(11) {
  flex-basis:25%;
}
.box span:nth-child(2),
.box span:nth-child(6),
.box span:nth-child(8),
.box span:nth-child(12) {
  height:12.5%;
}
span:before {
  content:counter(num);
  counter-increment:num;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span style="order:4"></span>
  <span style="order:1"></span>
  <span style="order:3"></span>
  <span style="order:6"></span>
  <span style="order:8"></span>
  <span style="order:11"></span>
  <span style="order:9"></span>
  <span style="order:12"></span>
  <span style="order:10"></span>
  <span style="order:7"></span>
  <span style="order:5"></span>
  <span style="order:2"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: amazing! One question the counting in your chart is horizontal. How do I change the counting to match the way it is in my example chart? Counting kinda goes in anti-clockwise.

Comment: @KapishM CSS counters cannot do this. Either you write the numbers manually or you consider the `order` property to change the order of the elements to have the result you want. In all the cases, there is some manual work but I don't think it's an issue since it's only about 12 elements.

Comment: Okay. Understood what you saying not possible for straight counting. But If I just skip that counting. And I want to address them in a series anti-clockwise to place values of an array in them. Can I index them anti-clockwise 1 to 12 as in example? Using id or by some other means?

Comment: @You are a genius! I am still trying to read your code and understand the magic you did. :)

Comment: @KapishM I also updated the gradient for an optimized version where you only need two gradient

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort!! Can I contact you for working on my project?

Comment: @KapishM yes sure, you can find a chat widget on my personal website shown in my profile

Answer (score 1):

You may also play with [mask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/mask) and position :

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

article {
  min-width: 30vmax;
  min-height: 20vmax;
  height: 80vh;
  width: 80vw;
  border: solid;
  counter-reset: divs;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: black;
}

div {
  clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 100% 50%, 50% 100%, 0% 50%);  /* make your diamond shape*/
  background: lightblue;
  counter-increment: divs;
  height: 50%;
  position: relative;
  transform: scale(0.99);  /* will show parent's bacground alike borders*/
}

div:nth-child(odd) {
  background: lightgreen;
}

div:before {
  content: counter(divs);
  margin: auto;
}

div:nth-child(2) {
  order: -1;
  top: -25%;
  left: 0;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

div:nth-child(1) {
  left: -25%;
}

div:nth-child(3) {
  left: -25%;
  top: -50%;
  padding-left: 15%;
}

div:nth-child(4) {
  left: -50%;
  top: -25%
}

div:nth-child(5) {
  left: -25%;
  top: -50%;
  padding-left: 15%
}

div:nth-child(6) {
  left: -50%;
  top: -25%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

div:nth-child(7) {
  left: 25%;
  top: -100%;
}

div:nth-child(8) {
  left: 0%;
  top: -75%;
  padding-bottom: 10%;
}

div:nth-child(9) {
  left: 75%;
  top: -150%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}

div:nth-child(10) {
  left: 0%;
  top: -175%;
}

div:nth-child(11) {
  left: 75%;
  top: -250%;
  padding-right: 15%;
}

div:nth-child(12) {
  left: 0;
  top: -275%;
  padding-top: 10%;
}

/* swap position */


article:hover {
  background: tomato;
}
article:hover div:nth-child(2) {
  left: 50%;
}
article:hover div:nth-child(12) {
  left: -50%;
}
article:hover div:nth-child(3) {
  left: 75%;
  padding: 0 10% 0 0;
}
article:hover div:nth-child(11) {
  left: -25%;
  padding: 0 0 0 10%;
}

article:hover div:nth-child(4) {
  left: 0%;
}
article:hover div:nth-child(10) {
  left: -50%;
}

article:hover div:nth-child(5) {
  left: 75%;
  padding: 0 10% 0 0;
}
article:hover div:nth-child(9) {
  left: -25%;
  padding: 0 0 0 10%;
}

article:hover div:nth-child(6) {
  left: 0%;
}
article:hover div:nth-child(8) {
  left: -50%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <article class="row flex-wrap m-auto">
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
    <div class="col-6 d-flex"> </div>
  </article>
```

https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWYmbEz

Comment: Lovely! I have the same question - How can I index this anti-clockwise 1 to 12? I want to place array values in it?  And Can this be responsive?

Comment: @KapishM it can rezise but will not reorder things while screen is rezized (play the snippet in full page to see what happens) . to reorder-things, you will need to reset the top and left position individually. position can be reset by step of 25% . i used your screenshot .to place these

Comment: @KapishM example how to set element somewhere else : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/MWYmbEz hover the box to see them going to the opposite left coordonates only is updated.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort on this. I can use this solution for generating output to pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for achieving the diagonal lines

```
.childDiv {
    border:1px solid gray;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    position:relative;
}

.childDiv:after {
    position:absolute;
    content:"";
    border-top:1px solid black;
    width:141px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform-origin: 0% 0%;
}
```

This will give you the diagonal line from top left to the bottom right corner. You can rotate it by a further 90° to get the diagonal from top right to bottom left.

`width:141px` is due to Pythagoras theorem. I took the sides as 100px, and hence, the hypotenuse(the diagonal in our case) must be 100√2 which is approximately 141.

You should divide your astrology chart into 4 divs as shown:
[image]

You can employ the above code to these 4 divs (marked with blue) and get the diagonal lines as necessary. Moreover, you will need to remove certain borders from some divs. See this:
[image]

To get the divs to form a square, you will need a total of 6 divs. 4 of these will be the divs marked in the image above, and 2 will be parent divs, which will hold 2 divs each.

Each parent div will hold 2 divs within in on each row. Think of the code as:

```
<div id='parentDiv1'>
  <div class='div1 childDiv'></div>
  <div class='div2 childDiv'></div>
</div>

<div id='parentDiv2'>
  <div class='div1 childDiv'></div>
  <div class='div2 childDiv'></div>
</div>
```

In your CSS file, you should add the following code:

```
#parentDiv1, #parentDiv2 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  float: left;
}
.div1 {
  float: left;
}
.div2 {
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: I will try. How do 4 divs position side by side to form one square?

Comment: @KapishM I have edited my answer to include the explanation.

Comment: I used this code as-is in https://codepen.io/pen/. Not seeing any shapes at all.

Comment: @KapishM Odd, it works for me. https://codepen.io/AdityaPrakash/pen/GRgmjdR. Note that this does not give you the exact code. You will still have to rotate the diagonals accordingly and remove the borders, but it gives you an idea about how to deal with it.

Comment: @KapishM Can you share your codepen again? You have not copied your pen link correctly.

Comment: Now I see it. Still far from the goal.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204666/discussion-between-aditya-prakash-and-kapish-m).